# Import Data to mailchimp and schedule email?

Tags: php, email, cakephp, mailchimp

I have an app on cakephp. I want to integrate it with mailchimp. What I want is to import user information from my database (email, name etc) on mailchimp (i know this could be possible via their api) but except the user details I also want to import more detail (e.g: client's order details from my app database.. etc). In a nutshell, what I exactly want is to import user details and their order details somewhere at mailchimp and by using their dashboard manually schedule emails for particualr users. Is this possible ?

p.s: I know I can use their api t integrate mailchimp with my app. But what I want is to upload data and use mailchimp dashboard for this scenrio

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [Mailchimp](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-mailchimp) - but your question is too broad and not specific enough.

Comment: Thanks mark. I just want to confirm is it possible to use their dashboard (the scenario I mentioned) rather using their api and do this from my cakephp app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their dashboard isn't going to be a great fit for this.  It's not really designed to give you a ton of client data.  You'd be better off just making your own dashboard that leverages their API for sending emails.